# xlwings ActiveX component can't create an object when importing UDFs

Tags: python, excel, vba, udf, xlwings

I have a sheet that is running user defined function from python xlwings.

When I try to open the same file from a different machine on the same network I get the error in the title when I click Import UDFs from the xlwings tab.

If I create a new blank file I can start writing user defined functions from it and I do not get the error. (I am mentioning this to clarify that xlwings and python are installed properly on the other machine as well).

How do I fix this??

Any ideas?

Thanks!